# Following a winding path with MoveIt

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot is designed spray concert on the inside of tunnel walls. It has a nozzle for spray at the end of a long arm.
To distribute the concrete, the nozzle has to be moved back and forth across the tunnel surface in a specific path.
Path description:

- Consists of horizontal lines along the tunnel surface.
- Semicircles connect the lines
- The nozzle (frame) must at all times be orientated towards the surface.
- The velocity of the nozzle should be near constant to ensure spread of on the concrete.

My question is: How can I utilize MoveIt to plan a path that satisfy these specifications?
Alternatively, could I define such a path myself, and let MoveIt create the joint trajectories?
Suggestions on better approaches are also appreciated, as I am a MoveIt novice.

Would gladly upload illustrative pictures if I get some points.

Any help appreciated :)

---

Edit: Thank you for the response @AndyZe, this seems like a very good approach. However, in discussion with my supervisor, we concluded that the input to the planning module should be a set of waypoints. At first, I experimented with the computeCartesianPath() function of MoveGroupInterface, then I tried to utilize setPoseTargets() as suggested by @sampreets3. Unfortunately, I have not been able to implement a working planner yet.
My issue is my waypoints are too strict:

- The robot only has 5 Degrees of freedom.
- The waypoints I have defined include orientation and position (6 DOF). Trough testing in Rviz, it is clear that many of the waypoints I defined for the robot are unreachable (in orientation).

However, I only need the x-axis of my end effector (nozzle) to point in a certain direction, the y and z-axis are irrelevant.
So my question is:
**Is it possible to define target poses where the orientation is not fully defined?**
Keep in mind that target orientation changes between the waypoints.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414504/following-a-winding-path-with-moveit/) by [Hennifre](https://answers.ros.org/users/135358/hennifre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2023-04-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would:

- Use moveit_cpp. [Tutorial here](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/moveit_cpp/moveitcpp_tutorial.html)
- Use the Pilz industrial motion planner to plan the circular segment and the line segments individually. [Tutorial here](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html?highlight=pilz)
- Write your own functions to parse the waypoints and retime them, since you know how fast the robot needs to move
- Then combine all the sub-trajectories into one large one.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2023-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2023-04-24**:
New info about 5-dof:

- Pilz definitely won't work for 5-dof
- You can use the bio_ik solver since it returns approximate solutions. This is an easy change in `kinematics.yaml`
- When requesting the motion plan, you can specify contstraints. TBH I haven't used this much so I'm not completely sure how it works:  https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_msgs/blob/master/msg/MotionPlanRequest.msg

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2023-04-24**:
By the way, do you happen to work for a company starting with "I", @Hennifre?

**Comment by [Hennifre](https://answers.ros.org/users/135358/hennifre/) on 2023-04-24**:
Thank you, @AndyZe, I will look into your suggestion.

I am working on my master thesis. The project is provided by a company, but it does not start with "I".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What @AndyZe has suggested would be quite robust, especially using the Pilz Motion Planner.

> Alternatively, could I define such a path myself, and let MoveIt create the joint trajectories?

You can take a look at the [setPoseTargets](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/6c5203338bf305e1a9303839ded3afebee423c78/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h#L642) function of MoveGroupInterface. I think this is close to what you want to pass in as inputs to the planning problem.

---

Originally posted by [sampreets3](https://answers.ros.org/users/87884/sampreets3/) with karma: 230 on 2023-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hennifre](https://answers.ros.org/users/135358/hennifre/) on 2023-04-24**:
I tested your suggestion, and would like to use the MoveGroupeInterface (MGI) as it is beginner-friendly. The problem is that the PoseTargets must be fully defined (position and orientation). Note the edit in my original post: my robot has 5 Degrees of freedom. MGI does not provide ways of relaxing the constraints on one specific orientation angle. The only options seem to be to relax the entire orientation constraint. I found this [pull request](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/2780) for adding the functionality I need, but unfortunately it has not come through yet ...